# How to calculate metrics "SDR", "SI-SDR", "SIR", "SAR" in Python?

Tags: python, audio, metrics

Let's say I have stereo music with length 10 seconds and sample rate = 44100, then after read music in numpy array shape will be `REF = (2, 441000)`.

I have the second version of this music with noise `EST = (2, 441000)`. And I want to calculate:

- Source-to-Distortion Ratio (SDR)
- Scale-invariant Source-to-Distortion Ratio (SI-SDR)
- Source-to-Interference Ratio (SIR)
- Source-to-Artifact Ratio (SAR)

Some information how to caluclate them is available here:
https://source-separation.github.io/tutorial/basics/evaluation.html

For SDR there was proposed the following formulae:
https://www.aicrowd.com/challenges/music-demixing-challenge-ismir-2021#evaluation-metric

And code:

```
def sdr(references, estimates):
    # compute SDR for one song
    delta = 1e-7  # avoid numerical errors
    num = np.sum(np.square(references), axis=(1, 2))
    den = np.sum(np.square(references - estimates), axis=(1, 2))
    num += delta
    den += delta
    return 10 * np.log10(num / den)
```

Is there the same code for SI-SDR, SIR and SAR?
Is there some other metrics to calculate denoise (or source separation) model quality?

Comment: You seem to have considered `e_interf`, `e_noise` and `e_artif` to be all embedded within your `estimates` sample. You need either to show how to derive those error values, or how to presume them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [original article](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00544230/document)

**Considering Π{y1,..., yk} as the orthogonal projector onto the subspace spanned by the vectors y1,..., yk. The projector is a T x T matrix, where T is the length of these vectors, you will first need to calculate three orthogonal projectors:**

`Psj  = Π{Sj}`

`Ps   = Π{(Sj') 1≤j'≤n}`

`Ps,n = Π{(Sj') 1≤j'≤n, (Ni) 1≤i≤m}`

`starget := Psj*Sj`

`einterf := Ps*Sj − Psj*Sj`

`enoise := Ps,n*Sj − Ps*Sj`

`eartif := Sj − Ps,n*Sj`

Once you have these calculations:

```
def sir(starget, einterf):
    # compute SIR for one song
    delta = 1e-7  # avoid numerical errors
    num = np.sum(np.square(starget), axis=(1, 2))
    den = np.sum(np.square(einterf), axis=(1, 2))
    num += delta
    den += delta
    return 10 * np.log10(num / den)
```

and:

```
def sar(starget, einterf, enoise, eartif):
    # compute SAR for one song
    delta = 1e-7  # avoid numerical errors
    num = np.sum(np.square(starget + einterf + enoise), axis=(1, 2))
    den = np.sum(np.square(eartif), axis=(1, 2))
    num += delta
    den += delta
    return 10 * np.log10(num / den)
```

The Scale-Invariant Source-to-Distortion Ratio (SI-SDR) aims to remedy the issues with SDR, by removing SDR’s dependency on the amplitude scaling of the signal. Here I recommend using the calculation published [here](https://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR2019-013.pdf) on page 4 (2.3. Scale-aware SDR).